# Как объединить массив с другим массивом с некоторым шагом?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Имею следующую задачу:

> Зашифрованный текст должен храниться в файле текстового формата вместе
>   с ключом. Перед записью в файл зашифрованного текста и ключа
>   предварительно перемешайте записываемые массивы (в получаемом массиве
>   выделяются фиксированные позиции для хранения символов ключа; для
>   корректной сборки ключа необходимо указать длину ключа в символах и
>   шаг фиксированных позиций, т.е. через сколько символов шифрованного
>   текста находятся символы ключа; указанные признаки можно записать в
>   качестве первых двух байтов файла или же в других позициях файла).

Мне помогли с алгоритмом и с кодом:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Input
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int step, word;
            string text, key, result = string.Empty;

            Console.Write("Enter Text : ");
            text = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter Key : ");
            key = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter Step : ");
            step = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            // MIX ARRAY
            word = 0;

            if (step <= text.Length)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < key.Length; i++)
                {
                    result += key.Substring(i, 1);
                    for (int k = 0; k < step; k++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            result += text.Substring(word, 1);
                            word++;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (word < text.Length)
                {
                    result += text.Substring(word, (text.Length - word));
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Result Text : " + result);

            // DECIPHER ARRAY

            Console.WriteLine("text: " + text);
            Console.WriteLine("key: " + key);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Только теперь я не могу правильно расшифровать перемешанную строку. 
**Входные данные:** длина ключа в символах (key.Length), шаг (step), перемешанная строка (result). 
**Выходные данные:** текст (text), ключ (key).

Comment: Не злоупотребляйте метками

Comment: Если у вас появился новый вопрос - задайте его отдельным сообщением

Comment: @Андрей если вопрос про массивы, нельзя поставить [tag:массивы] ?

Comment: @4per, можно, но зачем засорять топик кучей меток. А в этом конкретном примере вообще не имеет значения как хранятся данные и вообще хранятся ли. Смотрите ответ - он универсален и работает с любыми последовательностями `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну готовых алгоритмов я не помню. Но можно легко написать свой.

```
static IEnumerable<T> Mix<T>(IEnumerable<T> s1, IEnumerable<T> s2, int step1, int step2 = 1)
{
    using (var e1 = s1.GetEnumerator())
    using (var e2 = s2.GetEnumerator())
    {
        bool firstFinished = false, secondFinished = false;
        while (!firstFinished && !secondFinished)
        {
            if (!firstFinished)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < step1; i++)
                {
                    if (!e1.MoveNext())
                        firstFinished = true;
                    yield return firstFinished ? default(T) : e1.Current;
                }
            }
            if (!secondFinished)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < step2; i++)
                {
                    if (!e2.MoveNext())
                        secondFinished = true;
                    yield return secondFinished ? default(T) : e2.Current;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Неполные группы дополняются значением `default(T)`.

Пробуем:

```
var result = Mix(new [] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, new[] {100, 200}, 3).ToArray();
foreach (var v in result) Console.Write(v + " ");
```

Результат:

```
1 2 3 100 4 5 6 200 7 8 0 0
```

Comment: Возможно стоит в каждый `for` добавить что-то типа `if (firstFinished && secondFinished) yield break;`, чтобы не генерировать кучу завершающих нулей

Comment: @Андрей: В первый for по идее не нужно. А нужно ли во второй, вопрос к автору: может, он хочет, чтобы все блоки были одного размера.